# Is getting line number in log an inherent issue in nodejs that no logging library can resolve?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, logging, line-numbers

I was about to use winston in my app, then I realised it can't show function name/line number in the log, which I think is pretty important for debugging a server side application.

After some digging, I found an explanation on winston's github issues page [here](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/200).

They explained very clearly the reason is performance, getting stack trace on every logging call is very expensive.

However, when I looked for winston alternatives, I found a few libraries already provide features to log line number, for example Bunyan, [Scribe](https://github.com/bluejamesbond/Scribe.js) and [Bristol](https://github.com/TomFrost/Bristol). I looked at Bristol's source code, it has the following comment on `getOrigin` function:

```
/**
   * Finds the origin of the Bristol log call, and supplies the file path and
   * line number.
   * This function uses JavaScriptStackTraceApi to be as fast as possible:
   * https://code.google.com/p/v8-wiki/wiki/JavaScriptStackTraceApi
```

and I found the document about `JavaScriptStackTraceApi` [here](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Stack-Trace-API)

I'm just curious, is this the same type of stack trace the winston guys were talking about? **Is getting line number an inherent issue in nodejs that no logging library can resolve?**

I want line number logged but not with the price of heavy performance penalty. `Bristol` looks really good, have anyone seen a performance benchmark of it? or a performance benchmark of any logging library with line number feature turned on?

Comment: You should just measure performance yourself and compare Bristol with Winston. Then see whether the additional information is worth the cost for you.